# Django- How to make a dynamic template with ManyToManyField in model

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I'm new to Django. I'm trying to figure out how to get the tags property of MyModel (manytomany) onto the template (mytemplate.html) for each object in MyModel. Note: there are 4 possible tags in the Tags admin. Some of the objects from MyModel have 2 tags, some have 1. How do I get each object's unique selection of tags onto my template? Here are my files:

**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('dataset', 'dataset'),
        ('brand', 'brand'),
    )
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    publish_date = models.DateField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import MyModel, Tag

def index(request):

    tags = Tag.objects.all()

    infos = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('publish_date').reverse()

    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'infos': infos, 'tags':tags})
```

**mytemplate.html**

Right now this just creates 4 p elements- one for all 4 possible 'tags'

```
{% for info in infos %}
    <small>{{info.publish_date}}</small>
    {% for tag in tags %}
        <p>{{tag.tag}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
{% for info in infos %}
    <small>{{info.publish_date}}</small>
    {% for tag in info.tags.all %}
        <p>{{tag.tag}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```